# What's wrong with the syntax in my for loop?

Tags: c, for-loop

I'm trying to run this for loop but I keep getting the error that intellisense expected a ';' before the beginning of the loop and I'm not sure why? I've initialized j to 0 earlier in the main program.

```
for (j = 1, j < 1000, j++)
    J[j] = SumSquareDigits(N);
    N = SumSquareDigits(N);
```

Comment: Umm, because the commas should be semi-colons.

Answer (score 2):

```
for (j = 1, j < 1000, j++)
```

should be

```
for (j = 1; j < 1000; j++)
     |         |         |
     |         |         |
   Initialize  Condition  Update your variable
    your
   Variable
```

Comment: Wow, that's a bad mistake. Thank you!